# Old Testament Hebrew translation of (Psalm 31:18)'s "lying lips" be broad enough to include "pretentiousness" and/or "deceptiveness"?

Tags: hebrew, translation-philosophy, layers-of-meaning

Just out of curiosity, could someone please tell me if the Old Testament Hebrew translation of the phrase "lying lips"

1. Could be broad enough to also include "pretentiousness"?
2. Could be broad enough to also include "deceptiveness"?

> (Psalm 31:18)
>
> 18 Let the lying lips be mute, Which speak arrogantly
> against the righteous With pride and contempt.

> 31:18 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex תֵּ֥אָלַ֗מְנָה שִׂפְתֵ֫י
> שָׁ֥קֶר הַדֹּבְרֹ֖ות עַל־צַדִּ֥יק עָתָ֗ק בְּגַאֲוָ֥ה וָבֽוּז׃
>
> תהילים 31:18 Hebrew OT: WLC (Consonants Only) תאלמנה שפתי שקר הדברות
> על־צדיק עתק בגאוה ובוז׃
>
> תהילים 31:18 Paleo-Hebrew OT: WLC (Font Required) תאלמנה שפתי שקר
> הדברות על־צדיק עתק בגאוה ובוז׃
>
> תהילים 31:18 Hebrew Bible תאלמנה שפתי שקר הדברות על צדיק עתק בגאוה
> ובוז׃

Answer (score 2):

While Hebrew, like any language, is sometimes open to interpretation, judging from the usages made of the two Hebrew words at question it appears that one would go beyond the boundary of meaning to include pretentiousness, but would be well within limits to include deceptiveness.  However, Psalm 31:18 parallels the lying with arrogance somewhat in its couplet, giving some food for thought as to a possible connection between them.  Still, they are separate concepts.

The two Hebrew words in the expression translated as "lying lips" are "שִׂפְתֵ֫י שָׁ֥קֶר", referencing both "lips" and the "lying"/"falsehood"/"deceit"/"deception"/"falsity".  Both are nouns (no adjective here) which puts them into a Hebrew construct chain and could technically be translated like "lips of lying" or "lips of falsehood".